# Ruby on Rails: Two views, one save buffer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Just a note before you read this, I'm not a programmer in RoR but I just wanted to validate that this is possible, so sorry in advance.

I have a quick question about using a secondary page.  Here's how I want it to work:

I have a primary page that has some data that will be saved.  I have a link to a secondary page that you save only to the buffer. This means that if I change it three times everytime i go back to look at it it shows the last value I changed it to.

At save time of the primary page, I want the information on the primary page and the secondary page to be validated and saved.  If it fails, I don't want to save the information on either page.  Is this possible in RoR?  If so can someone explain to me how?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in a few ways:

- Have one real page, but use JavaScript to hide and show parts of it as needed.
- Store the object in the session, and only write it to the database at the end
- Store the data in a temporary table and save it in the real table at the end